# Display text in a column based on what is in two columns

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have two columns [Impact] and [Urgency] that are choices - I would like to display text in another column based on the choices in those columns.

if[impact]=High and [Urgency]=High then display "Crisis - SEV1"

Can someone help me?

thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(AND([impact]="High", [Urgency]="High"), "Crisis - SEV1", "Low Severity")
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.
3. You can replace "Low Severity" text according to your requirements.

**official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: thank you Ganesh! i will give it a try and let you know how i make out :)

Comment: it worked!!  if i have impacts that are medium and low - would i duplicate the code?

Comment: clicked add too soon - would i do =IF(AND([impact]="High", [Urgency]="High"), "Crisis - SEV1", "Low Severity"), =IF(AND([impact]="medium", [Urgency]="High"), "Crisis - SEV1", "Medium Severity"), =IF(AND([impact]="Low", [Urgency]="High"), "Crisis - SEV1", "Low Severity")

Comment: You can not do like this in same calculated column. You will need to use nested IF functions to get it working based on your requirements.

Comment: Hi Ganesh!  it worked as you suggested: 
 For those who have a similar question - this worked for me: IF(AND(Impact="High",Urgency="Low"),"Event - SEV3",IF(AND(Impact="Medium",Urgency="High"),"Incident - SEV2",IF(AND(Impact="Medium",Urgency="Medium"),"Event - SEV3",IF(AND(Impact="Medium",Urgency="Low"),"Occurrence - SEV4",IF(AND(Impact="Low",Urgency="High"),"Event - SEV3",IF(AND(Impact="Low",Urgency="Medium"),"Occurrence - SEV4",IF(AND(Impact="Low",Urgency="Low"),"Occurrence - SEV4","NA")))))))))

Comment: Great. I am glad, you got it working. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others having similar question.